# Raspberry Pi 4 Ethernet not Connecting

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, pi-4

I have a raspberry Pi 4 with raspbian, and I just booted it and connected it to ethernet.
My Router does not detect the pi, so I cant ssh into it. I tried 2 different SD cards, and they both will boot on my Pi 0.

Comment: Replace the cable between your RPi & your router with a known good cable.

Comment: You need access to an HDMI screen and a computer keyboard.

Comment: Is this a fresh install on the card, or an old one you used with the Pi Zero? Also what version of Raspbian are you using? You need to be using Buster to support the Pi 4

Comment: How do you know you have booted, do you have a screen/terminal attached? If this is the case, please post the output of `ifconfig` and `ip route list`.

Comment: Have you used a network scanner to find ip addresses on your network?

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi 4 does not connect over the ethernet port with just any cable.
To connect mine to the network I had to use a Gigabit cable, only then the LEDs turned on and the Pi connected.

Answer (score 1):

Rodolfo's answer addresses it but if you are in a situation where you don't have a Gigabit ethernet cable (cat6 or so) and have some way to access the terminal, then you can force the raspberry pi ethernet interface to operate at 100Mbps.

Following command can help if run from the terminal:

```
# ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full
```

Until you can replace the cable with a Gigabit cable, you may want this to be executed on boot too. One way to do that would be to use `@reboot` in your crontab entry. There, you may need to add a few seconds delay as well (e.g. using `sleep`).

Answer (score 0):

FredTheDoggy.

As you're trying to SSH, I'm assuming you don't have a monitor. If you have one, then please share the result of `ifconfig` with us.

You've to keep these things in mind before connecting your RPi:

1. Make sure you're using a standard cat5/cat6 cable with an RJ45 connector, and it's not broken.
2. You should have a clean installation of Raspberry Pi OS Buster on your card, and it shouldn't be used on any other old Raspberry Pis. If you're not using a clean installation, then please reinstall the OS and try again.
3. Make sure that you're connecting the ethernet cable to the correct port on your router.

Comment: You should ask for `ifconfig -a` (or `ip link`), as all by itself all it will show are interfaces that are up and connected, which eth0 in this case probably isn't.